# Setting up Tomcat 7 and NetBeans/Eclipse

Tags: tomcat, xampp, netbeans-7

I have problems with setting up the Tomcat.
I have installed xampp and I can't setup the ports, both the Apache and the tomcat are using 8080 ports.
I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, you'll need to change the listening port for either Tomcat or Apache. Look for a `Connector` with `port="8080"` in conf/server.xml and change it there, or in your Apache httpd.conf.

Comment: I found the conf.xml and I changed into this:
    <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8553" />